# FTP Upload and Download via PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, codeigniter, ftp

What's the best way to implement FTP upload and download in PHP? I'm using CodeIgniter and have Zend libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeigniter has an FTP Class http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/ftp.html.

Include this extension for reverse mirror/download support http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/157098/